# i want to display the events that user set to days of calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, event-handling, alpine.js, persian-calendar

I am using alpine js and this project is a Persian calendar. I created all part of this calendar and it has an event. The user can set a note to each day and by click on that day can read the note.

Now I want to display the note on that day but when I return them on days, my calendar will return days with number under 0 or wrong numbers and I really don't understand what is the problem.

this the function that render the note on day

```
        showEventDay(d){ 
          const exatDay = `${this.year}/${this.month}/${d - this.daysGone}`;
          const eventForDay = this.events.find(e => e.date === exatDay);
          console.log(eventForDay);
          if(eventForDay){
            return eventForDay.title;
          }
        },
```

and this a span that revise the note

```
     <span x-text="showEventDay(days)"></span>
```

this the loop for render the days of month

```
        <template x-for="days in allDays">
          <div
            :class="setDayClass(days)"
            @click="openModal(`${year}/${month}/${days - daysGone}`)"
          >
            <template x-if="days > daysGone">
              <div class="flex flex-row justify-between bordered">
                <p x-text="days - daysGone"></p>
                <!-- <span x-text="showEventDay(days)"></span> -->

              </div>
            </template>

            <template x-if="days <= daysGone">
              <div></div>
            </template>
          </div>
        </template>
```

wen i uncomment that span events(notes) will show prefect but the count of days when i move between month will be messy.

this is how i move between months

```
        changeMonthSelect(e){
          switch(e.value) {
            case 'فرو':
              this.monthIndex = 1;
              this.load();
              break;
            case 'ارد':
              this.monthIndex = 2;
              this.load();
              break;
            case 'خرد':
              this.monthIndex = 3;
              this.load();
              break;
            case 'تیر':
              this.monthIndex = 4;
              this.load();
              break;
            case 'مرد':
              this.monthIndex = 5;
              this.load();
              break;
            case 'شهر':
              this.monthIndex = 6;
              this.load();
              break;
            case 'مهر':
              this.monthIndex = 7;
              this.load();
              break;
            case 'آبا':
              this.monthIndex = 8;
              this.load();
              break;
            case 'آذر':
              this.monthIndex = 9;
              this.load();
              break;
            case 'دی':
              this.monthIndex = 10;
              this.load();
              break;
            case 'بهم':
              this.monthIndex = 11;
              this.load();
              break;
            case 'اسف':
              this.monthIndex = 12;
              this.load();
              break;
            default:
              this.monthIndex = Number(this.month);
          } 
        },
```

and this condition

```
          //change the month
          if(this.monthIndex !== Number(this.month)){
            const currentMonth = this.monthIndex;
            this.month = new persianDate([Number(this.year),currentMonth,Number(this.day)]).toLocale('en').format('MM');
            this.monthName = new persianDate([Number(this.year),currentMonth,Number(this.day)]).toLocale('fa').format('MMM');
          }else if(this.month == '' && this.monthName == ''){
            this.month = dt.toLocale('en').format('MM'); 
            this.monthName = dt.toLocale('fa').format('MMM'); 
            this.today = Number(this.month);
            this.monthIndex = Number(this.month);
          }
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve] and remove all unrelated code and HTML

Comment: i didt what you want

Comment: No. You removed my snippet and posted loose code. Please click [edit], then click the button that looks like `[<>]` and paste relevant JS in the javascript pane, relevant HTML in the HTML pane and relevant CSS in the CSS pane. Then add whatever other libraries to the HTML pane from CDN. I even GAVE you the script tags for the alpine